# Cheerio unmatched selector error while selecting plain text

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm scraping a web page with cheerio's .map method. The page's html code looks like this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    TEXT WITHOUT TAG
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Here is what I do:

```
let $ = cheerio.load(body);
let contentHtml = $('foo').html();
$(contentHtml).map((index, element) => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

When .map see the 'TEXT WITHOUT TAG', it throws an error like this:

```
Unmatched selector: ...
```

Which is expected because it hasn't any selectors. I want to wrap that plain text with `<p>` tags but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Your element has class `foo` and selector not:

```
let contentHtml = $('.foo').html();
```

Comment: This is not the point. I want to select plain text with .map method.